# Can you average ICC values for Intra-rater reliability?

Tags: intraclass-correlation

I am using ICCs to test the inter- and intra-rater reliability for a body condition scoring system. I have two different groups of evaluators: specialists and students. I would like to evaluate the intra-rater reliability when the raters are asked to score the same photo two different times, to insure that the rater can reliably give the same photo the same body condition score. I have 7 raters in the specialist group, they each scored the same 10 photos on two different occasions. I can calculate the ICC value for intra-rater reliability by comparing the scores of the same photos given by the same evaluator at two different time points. However, this would only tell me the intra-rater reliability for that one rater. Am I able to average these ICC values for all 7 raters in the specialist group to get an average ICC value for intra-rater reliability for the specialist as a whole rather than individually? If so, I am assuming I would just take the average of the ICC values from each of the 7 specialist to get an average ICC value. However, I am not sure how I would get an average of the 95% confidence interval. Would I take the averages of the confidence intervals also. This does not seem statistically correct, but I am just not sure. Thanks.